# Electric field from conductive to dielectric media

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, boundary-conditions

I am interested in the main difference between transitions from electric fields from Conductive to Conductive/ Dielectric to Dielectric and Dielectric/Conductive media.

What are the boundary conditions that an Electric field and a potential has to fulfill?
I think I only know it for dielectric to dielectric media, where the potential has to be continuous and the electric field changes by the amount of surface charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These boundary conditions depend only on the charge distribution of the boundary and can be obtained directly from Maxwell's equations.

The quantity that really matters is the total surface charge density at the boundary:
$$\sigma_{total}=\sigma_b+\sigma_{free}$$

In the boundary of two dielectrics, each dielectric will cause a bounded surface charge density of $\sigma_b =\mathbf{P}.\hat n$. So in the boundary of two dielectrics:

$$\sigma_b=\mathbf{P}_1.\hat n-\mathbf{P}_2.\hat n$$

In the boundary of a conductor and a dielectric you will have a surface charge density caused by polarization of the dielectric and also a surface charge density to make the electric field zero in the conductor. (static case, as is your question tagged)

The following is the most convenient form when dealing with conductor to dielectric boundaries:
$$\mathbf{D}.\hat n=\sigma_f\tag{$\sigma_f$ is free charge density}$$

So the quantity that really matters is the charge distribution of the boundary.

And in general when you have a surface charge density of $\sigma$ , the boundary conditions will be:

$$V_1=V_2$$

$$\mathbf{E_2}.\hat n-\mathbf{E_1}.\hat n=\frac{\sigma_{total}}{\epsilon_0}$$

Comment: Thank you, and if I have an electric field in vacuum and put a piece of metal(for example a sphere) in there(so we have the transition between dielectric and conducting media). which law gives me the electric field in the metal sphere and outside the metal sphere, do you know this?

Comment: @Lipschitz These boundary conditions are not enough to determine the fields completely, but if you mean what the boundary condition will be, it will be $\mathbf{D}.\hat n=0$ or equivalently $\epsilon_1\frac{\partial V}{\partial n}=0$ if the sphere doesn't have any free charge. Is there anything unclear?

Comment: I would interpret your last equation as that the normal component of the electric field on a metal sphere is zero, but I do not see why this should be. Well, what needs to be done to fully determine the electric field of a conducting medium in an external field?

Comment: @Lipschitz When you put a metal sphere in an external field, $\sigma_f $is *not* zero, and the boundary condition will be $\mathbf{E}.\hat n={\sigma\over \epsilon_0}$.In the above comment I didn't consider this. To determine the field completely you should apply other boundary conditions (say, at $\infty$) too.